# Not able to find reference model property in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two models and two routes files. But one property inside the object is not returning anything.

```js
// orders.js route
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Order = require('../models/order');

orderRouter.route('/')
.post((req, res, next) => {
  const order = new Order({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
    product: req.body.productId
  });
  order
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      res.status(201).json(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});

// order.js Model
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    // without required: true working but not returning anything
    product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Product', required: true},
    quantity:{ type: Number, default:1 }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

```js
// product.js model
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,    
    name: { type:String, required:true},
    price: { type: Number, required: true}
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

// products.js route


const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Product = require("../models/product");

productRouter
 .route("/")
  .get((req, res, next) => {
    Product.find()
      // SELECT SPECIFIC FIELDS TO DISPLAY
      .select('name price _id')
      .exec()
      .then(docs => {
        const response = {
          // To display item conts
          count: docs.length,
          // To display array of selected items
          products: docs.map(doc => {
            return {
              name: doc.name,
              price: doc.price,
              _id: doc._id,
              request: {
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/products/' + doc._id
              }
            }
          })
        };
        res.status(200).json(response)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err
        })
      })
  })
  
  .post((req, res, next) => {
    const product = new Product({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      name: req.body.name,
      price: req.body.price
    });
    product
      .save()
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Created Product successfully",
          createdProduct: {
            name: result.name,
            price: result.price,
            _id: result._id,
            request: {
              type: 'GET',
              url: 'http://localhost:3000/products/' + result._id
            }
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: err });
      });
  });
```

If I insert required: true in the order model then I am getting the error like this. `Path product is required. name": "ValidatorError"`. I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Without validations in model. I can post and get id,quantity but no luck with product.

Comment: You need to add Product schema code, and the query code.

Comment: I guess an order may have an array of products, but in your Order schema you didn't specified product field as array. Do you want only one product per order?

Comment: While posting the new product I used  array. What i am doing is getting all products and using single product id in the orders.

Comment: I will come with an alternative schema and solution.

Comment: I am referring to this video https://youtu.be/VKuY8QscZwY?list=PL55RiY5tL51q4D-B63KBnygU6opNPFk_q

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to get an order with it's products populated?

Comment: In that video, the author modeled the order schema to have one product for simplicity, in real world there is no such thing.

Comment: Okay but why product property is not returning anything. Whatever the author used is outdated or i am doing it wrong

Comment: Describe what do you want to achieve? For example, do you want to get the products in a specific order?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209396/discussion-between-ananyabingo-and-suleymansah).

Answer (score 0):

what is your POST look like?

`
POST http://localhost:8000/orders 
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "productId": "5e8b7ab88466300b9c720e68",
    "quantity": "10"
}
`

You should have "productId" and "quantity" in your POST request.